# Bootstrap sticky (fixed) alerts prevents scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a simple sticky-plugin addon for bootstrap. Basically, it works like this:

```
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() < ScrollPastOffset ) {
        console.log("max it");
        $(fixedAlertWrappers).removeClass('scroll');
    } else {
        console.log('min it');
        $(fixedAlertWrappers).addClass('scroll');
    }
```

But when you try to scroll past the alert, it causes a glitch and won't let you scroll down past the value you set in `ScrollPastOffset`. Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/09kh5rp9/

Answer (score 0):

your variable `ScrollPastOffset` needs to change when the content height increases

```
var topDist = $("a.btn").position();
if (scroll > topDist.top){
    console.log("max it");
    $(fixedAlertWrappers).removeClass('scroll');
}
else {
    console.log('min it');
    $(fixedAlertWrappers).addClass('scroll');
}
```

In your case you just need to edit this variable, rest of the code is same

```
var ScrollPastOffset = $("a.btn").position().top;
```

Here's a working [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNbrPR?editors=1111)

Comment: This causes it to never maximize again when you scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: I updated my answer. you just need to change one variable.

Comment: Also Use transform property in your header's css so that it happens smoothly not so sudden.

Comment: Example of using transform to make it smooth? Also I have had to use the code in my answer as for some reason yours does not work for me when I put it in my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough solution:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var elm = $('.fixed-alert-wrapper');
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() < 150 ) {
        if ( elm.hasClass('scroll') )
            elm.removeClass('scroll');
    } else {
        if ( !elm.hasClass('scroll') )
            elm.addClass('scroll');
    }
});
```